# Wordpress Media Library select multiple images on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, multiple-select, media-library, wordpress-media

I have enqueued `wp_enqueue_media();` on the frontend.

I have dded two kind of buttons, one for single selection and the second for multiple images selection

```
if($(this).hasClass('multiple-image-button')) {
            // Set the wp.media attributes
            var send_attachment_multiple = wp.media({
                title : 'Choose or Upload an Image',
                multiple: true,
                library: {
                    type: [ 'image' ]
                },
            });
        } else {
            //uploadSingleImages(this);
            // Set the wp.media attributes
            var send_attachment_multiple = wp.media({
                title : 'Choose or Upload an Image',
                multiple: false,
                library: {
                    type: [ 'image' ]
                },
            });
        }
```

Everything is working fine with this. Now the issue i think is the way how wordpress media library works with multiple image selection. when selecting multiple images it force the user to click shift/ctrl and image click to select all needed images (which is ok for desktop).

Now when i am on mobile i cant select multiple images even if multiple selection equals `true`.

**This is how it works currently (usual wordpress behaviour also on the backend)**
[image]

**This is how it should work for multiple image selection (on click without shift/ctrl/etc..)**
[image]

What is the best way to enable the bulk selection when trying to select multiple images? or there is any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I couldn't imagine that the solution could be so easy. After spending many hours i could find the solution.. So if you want to select multiple images without using shift/ctrl/etc which means only on click, you need to replace

```
multiple: true,
```

with

```
multiple: 'add',
```

Comment: can you add the full code snippet and its location?